# Performance issues with Hyperledger transactions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm working on a simple Hyperledger Composer-based system. Everything is deployed to an Ubuntu t2.medium instance on AWS, and the NodeJS backend runs in its own container.

Now, every time I add an asset or a participant (`getAssetRegistry` + `add`), it takes 2-3s to complete. On my (Windows) laptop, the same code takes 200-300ms. The only difference is that I don't put the backend app into a container. However, that can't be the issue, since read-only requests run pretty fast on the deployed system.

What could cause such a difference? Should I add more RAM or CPU?

Comment: 'runs in its own container' - I assume on AWS?  Have you tried to an analyser like tcpdump  between the two to see what's going on? Yes, more RAM and CPU could be a factor, but would start with seeing what 'transience' you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling up definitely helps. I conducted some load tests when [evaluating Hyperledger Composer](https://www.infoq.com/articles/evaluating-hyperledger-composer) recently and found that I could half the average latency when I switched from an m4.xlarge to an m4.2xlarge EC2 instance type.